# Elasticsearch is not defined while connecting to elastic search using python 3

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

Hello I am trying to connect elastic search(6.4.2) using python.I have already used command pip install elasticsearch
Below is the sample code :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


es = Elasticsearch()
```

It is giving me error that Elasticsearch is not defined.Please help to resolve this.Thanks in advance.